# Regex to get javascript function calls using preg_match_all in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I make a curl request to a server which returns javascript and I need to get each of the `addNewEvent` functions returned into a PHP array. So I figured I would use preg_match_all.

Unfortunately regex is not my strong point and I keep getting it wrong. Could someone please help me out with this?

I have this so far:

`'/addNewEvent\(\{(.*)\}\);/s'`

This is a snippet from the javascript containing the functions I need. The rest of the javascript does contain if statements with braces:

```
addNewEvent({id:2, type:1,
start: new Date(2012,02-1,10,09,00),
end:new Date(2012,02-1,10,10,00), 
startRounded:new Date(2012,1,10,9,0),
endRounded:new Date(2012,1,10,10,0),
desc:"test", allDay:0, recurring:0, reminder:0,
comment:"this is a tes\\\'st\\\"",
labelColor:\'#FF9281\', numOverlaps:0, overlapNumber:0});
addNewEvent({id:3, type:1,
start: new Date(2012,02-1,10,09,00),
end:new Date(2012,02-1,10,10,00), 
startRounded:new Date(2012,1,10,9,0),
endRounded:new Date(2012,1,10,10,0),
desc:"test 2", allDay:0, recurring:0, reminder:0,
comment:"",
labelColor:\'#849CE7\', numOverlaps:0, overlapNumber:0});
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 13:23**

Ideally I would like to have returned an array containing the JSON objects from inside the javascript function calls:

```
array(
    [0] => '{id:2, type:1,
        start: new Date(2012,02-1,10,09,00),
        end:new Date(2012,02-1,10,10,00), 
        startRounded:new Date(2012,1,10,9,0),
        endRounded:new Date(2012,1,10,10,0),
        desc:"test", allDay:0, recurring:0, reminder:0,
        comment:"this is a tes\\\'st\\\"",
        labelColor:\'#FF9281\', numOverlaps:0, overlapNumber:0}',
    [1] => '{id:3, type:1,
        start: new Date(2012,02-1,10,09,00),
        end:new Date(2012,02-1,10,10,00), 
        startRounded:new Date(2012,1,10,9,0),
        endRounded:new Date(2012,1,10,10,0),
        desc:"test 2", allDay:0, recurring:0, reminder:0,
        comment:"",
        labelColor:\'#849CE7\', numOverlaps:0, overlapNumber:0}'
);
```

Comment: What do you want to extract **exactly**? Show us an example.

Comment: You can't do this **reliably** with regular expression. The language is not regular. You might be able to get a solution that works in most cases though. Consider another solution to the problem.

Comment: Thanks Yotaware, I had suspected so.

Comment: As long as you want to catch everything that is between ' addNewEvent('and ');', I think it's not a problem with regexp. But, beware that by default, regexp are greedy, i.e they catch the longest expression that match. So you might catch everything from the first 'addNewEvent(' to the last '});' wherever it is. You have to modify the regexp to make it ungreedy. Not sure (didn't have time to check), but try adding 'U' after the '/s'.

Comment: huelbois - Thanks, that is what I have been experiencing. However, adding the U did solve the problem and provides me with an array containing two function calls.

Comment: inhan, I'm guessing you mean why don't I get the server to return JSON? Unfortunately I have no control over what the server returns.

Comment: Well, it works on my desk, using /sU. I get 2 answers in $matches[1][0] and $matches[1][1] ($matches being the third param to preg_match_all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full test (I've replaced some single quotes by double quotes to use heredoc syntax) :

```
$pattern='/addNewEvent\(\{(.*)\}\);/sU';

$subject='addNewEvent({id:2, type:1,
start: new Date(2012,02-1,10,09,00),
end:new Date(2012,02-1,10,10,00), 
startRounded:new Date(2012,1,10,9,0),
endRounded:new Date(2012,1,10,10,0),
desc:"test", allDay:0, recurring:0, reminder:0,
comment:"this is a tes\\\"st\\\"",
labelColor:\"#FF9281\", numOverlaps:0, overlapNumber:0});
addNewEvent({id:3, type:1,
start: new Date(2012,02-1,10,09,00),
end:new Date(2012,02-1,10,10,00), 
startRounded:new Date(2012,1,10,9,0),
endRounded:new Date(2012,1,10,10,0),
desc:"test 2", allDay:0, recurring:0, reminder:0,
comment:"",
labelColor:\"#849CE7\", numOverlaps:0, overlapNumber:0});';

print '<pre>';
if(preg_match_all($pattern,$subject,$matches)){
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```